# Terminal games like nethack?

Tags: linux, terminal, gaming

I recently stumbled upon [nethack](http://www.nethack.org/) while searching for linux games, and I must say it is amazing. As a result, I also found about [BSDgames](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/BSD_games) and have played most of the games in there. Are there any other linux terminal games such as nethack out there which are rather fun to play?

Comment: Not constructive, and off topic here or for [gaming.se] because it is a direct product recommendation question.  See the [FAQ#dontask] for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the fascination with old-tech computer games continues!

I'm old enough to remember when this kind of game was cutting edge. Back around 1978, interacting with a computer usually mean using a character terminal (like the [VT100](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100) that XTerm emulates) connected to time-shared central computer, usually running UNIX. There were a lot of different terminals using different escape codes, so the [curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)) library was invented so that programmers would have a terminal-independent API.

Aside from Rogue and its open-source derivitive Nethack, few early curses-based games were all that interesting. But 30+ years later [game designers are still in love with the API](https://www.google.com/search?q=curses+library+games).

And if curses games aren't retro enough for you, check out [Adventure](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/GAMES-ENTERTAINMENT/Puzzle/adventure-65223.shtml), a game where the command line is your input device and your imagination is your graphics adapter. This game spawned a whole [genre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_fiction).

Answer (score 0):

There are.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_roguelike_video_games

And that's just similar to NetHack. If you're looking for more terminal games, the BSD games is obviously a great place to start, but there were quite a few. There's the whole genre of interactive fiction for example.